# Term for one snapshot of dynamic data

Tags: terminology

I want to introduce the data I have taken from a dynamic dataset (GitHub repos) at 12pm today. I want to say the equivalent of "This is the data as of 12pm Sept 4" but am wondering if there is a specific term for that type of snapshot.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. No special need for one, either. Just use the KISS principle.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question, even if the answer is 'no'. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *cross-section* of your data. Such measurements are termed *cross-sectional*. A stream of such measurements is a *cross-sectional time series*. A cross-sectional time series, and a repeated cohorts time series (measuring *change* at repeated intervals of measurement) are both termed *panel time series*.